# How to write functional interface with cmake language?

Tags: c++, cmake

I found many project with CMake building system will create some_independent_function.CMake.

For example, folly and other Facebook library. They use variable like FOLLY_INCLUDE with CMake recommended naming rules to mark input and output for function to find folly project. Obviously it uses implicit variable as output.

How could I get some structured information for in and out, like

```golang
A_Standard_Package_Info_Object, err = package.find_package(Findfolly.cmake)
```

I want some closure feature with CMake. How could I set parameters as input and use return as output? Or could I encapsulate some function into a package rather than use
scripts file with implicit variables?

Comment: you can't do that in cmake, the best you can do is pass in a variable name or prefix into a function and the function can put it's result(s) into the named variables

Comment: [Modern CMake](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) encourages library CMake definitions to declare targets that can be linked to with all the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how the CMake language works. It is not designed to have such returns. Implicit variable names is the way to go.

Feel free to dislike for this design choices, then you are in good company :-)

Comment: "C++ is sophisticated enough, why we suffer so much in building?" That might be what the very first CMake author were thinking.